# How to get to first character of Mac/Unix Command Prompt?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

Driving me crazy! Say I'm typing on the terminal and I want to quickly get to the first character on the line, right now i use left arrow one press at a time and thinking there needs to be like a PAGE_HOME button to do that in the terminal, please help!? - Duncan Krebs

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to jump to the beginning of the line, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to jump to the end.

Comment: Great that it helped. Please mark the answer as _accepted_ by clicking on the checkmark.